# Users fields on front end form

Tags: users, form

Is it possible to include a Users Fields Type on a front end form? I'd like to allow people to choose existing users on a front end form rather than giving them access to the admin area of the Craft site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure is!  You'll want to bookmark this [ridiculously handy page](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input), but if you look under "Relations" you'll see the syntax you're looking for:

```
<select multiple name="fields[fieldHandle][]">
    <option value="13">Username One</option>
    <option value="42">Username Two</option>
    <option value="144">Username Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Brad! Would I be able to use code to include all users in a specified user group or do I need to list them all out like the code above?

Comment: Just use `craft.users.group` to the ones in the group you're looking for. https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.users#group